# unable to retrieve grouped dataframe using get_group function in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I used group by function of pandas and then i am trying to retrieve each grouped data frame separately using get_group function of pandas by passing keys to the get_groups , I have encountered an error.

since everything is library based i am not sure why i am getting error

```
data_grouped_by_common_columns=complete_df.groupby(common_columns)
final_df=pd.DataFrame()
print(data_grouped_by_common_columns.groups.keys())
for eachvalue in data_grouped_by_common_columns.groups.keys():
    grouped_df = data_grouped_by_common_columns.get_group(eachvalue)
    print(grouped_df)
```

i recieved the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\sanalama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 811, in get_group
    raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: ('accesslog', 'fa_ha', 'bi_server', nan)
```

since there is nothing much coding i have done, it is simply using the functions of pandas , i am not able to debug why this error is coming , because groups are being created by library itself , i am trying retrieve the grouped dataframe using library (existed one). is this because of nan values?

Comment: Please provide data sample. What is your complete_df and common_columns?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. My dataset has `nan` values in one of the column categories and I am using that column in the `groupby` function, so grouping is working but retrieving data using `get_group` is not working because of `nan` values. I just renamed all `nan` values to `Not applicable` and the same code worked fine.